# Coldfusion - Loading order for CFIDE scripts

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I have a Coldfusion page that includes a number of javascript files and css files in the header, as well as a number of CFIDE/scripts that are included by Coldfusion in the header (eg cfform.js and cfajax.js).

I have been told that to help speed up page loading and for a smoother page load, that css
files should be loaded prior to script files. In my header, I have made sure that all script
files are included below css files however the CFIDE/Script files included by coldfusion always appear at the top and I can't seem to find a way to prevent this.

If someone knows how to accomplish this, it would be appreciated. Thanks.

My pages currently load (if not already in cache) very "staggered" like, bits and pieces at a time..so any other suggestions to improve that would also be very much appreciated..

Comment: Unless you don't use any of the cfide scripts, which a lot of people on this site recommend, that situation is probably beyond your control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which web server are you using and are you an administrator?  If so, I use ColdFusion 8, 9 & 10 with IIS and have started using IISpeed (A Google PageSpeed port) to manage organization, location, caching, consolidation, deferring, minification of JS & CSS resources. (This will even optimize the unoptimized CFIDE production code that Adobe ships.)

http://www.iispeed.com/

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

The PageSpeed module allows me to focus on the code and let an automated process take over the optimization using best practices.

I can easily control what is optimized by using the "iispeed.config" file in the root of the website and adding CFHeader tags to enable & choose which filters to apply:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/experiment

If you want to use ColdFusion to do everything, you could try using CFStatic, but it won't provide you as much benefit as using PageSpeed:

http://cfstatic.riaforge.org/

To do comparison testing, use the Visual Comparison tool at WebPageTest.org and test different browsers as well as mobile. (PageSpeed can generate WebP images for Chrome on-the-fly.):

http://www.webpagetest.org/video/

Comment: Wow thanks for all of that James. I am using Coldfusion 10 and do have administrator access. It will take me bit of time to chew through all of the info/options you have provided although I am definitely leaning towards using iispeed. Thank for that.